# sending get through ajax javascript pure ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The ajax function is located in the header of my index page
function.

```
 myFunction(theVar) {

            var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

            var url = "includes/file.php";

            if (theVar.includes("postId")) {
                url = url + "?postId" + "=" + theVar.substr(theVar.length - 1);
            } else if (theVar.includes("userId")) {
                url = url + "?userId" + "=" + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);
            } else if (theVar.includes("commentId")) {
                url = url + "?commentId" + "=" + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);        
            }
            alert(url);


            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  alert("Success!");
                }
              };
            xhr.open('GET', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.send();
            return xhr;
        }
```

I get alert of url, and success when triggering the function but id's aren't interpreted by file.php.

Can any one help?

The PHP script

```
<?php

    require ('connection.php');
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === "XMLHttpRequest") { 
        if (isset($_GET['postId']) && !empty($_GET['postId'])) { 
            $postId= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
            $_GET['postId']); 

            if (isset($postId) && !empty($postId)) { 
                mysqli_query = ($link, "UPDATE posts SET postVotes = postVotes + 1 WHERE postId = {$postId}"); 
            } 
        } 
    } else { die("You are not allowed to access this file..."); }
?>
```

Comment: already checked for the request header in file.php

Comment: can you show how this is invoked?

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('postId<?php echo $post['postId']; ?>');">Click me</button>

Comment: btw: the php is vulnerable to sql injection ~ consider using a prepared statment instead of embedding variables within the sql itself...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

```
url = url + "commentId" + "=" + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);
```

It should be:

```
url = url + "?commentId" + "=" + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);
```

On the PHP side you need to "catch" your variable with `$_GET["commentId"]`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php

Edit:

```
<?php
require ('connection.php');
if (isset($_GET['postId'])) { //  no need for && !empty($_GET['postId']) if isset is used
  $postId = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['postId']);
  if (isset($postId)) { // no need for && !empty($postId) if isset is used
    //mysqli_query = ($link, "UPDATE posts SET postVotes = postVotes + 1 WHERE postId = {$postId}");
    echo "UPDATE posts SET postVotes = postVotes + 1 WHERE postId = {$postId}" // test
    }
    else {
      echo "postId is empty!";
    }
}
```

Now test it using for example `localhost/your.php?postId=2`

Comment: If my updated answer works it's the `$_SERVER` variables causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a peculiar way to structure the variable, especially given that you need to further process it to get the ID you need. You could make it simpler like this? The benefit of this would be that you can send many parameters without needing to modify the internal portion of the function - simply add more parameters/values to the `theVar` variable object.

The html

```
<button type='button' onclick='myFunction( { postId:<?php echo $post['postId']; ?> } );'>Click me</button>
```

the javascript

```
<script>

    const myFunction=function( theVar ) {
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'includes/file.php';

        var query=[];
        Object.keys( theVar ).map( function( key ){
            query.push( key+'='+theVar[key] )
        } );
        url+='?'+query.join('&');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert('Success!');
            }
          };
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.send();
    }

</script>
```

That said, after minor editing the below worked OK for me just now. The PHP code I used is below too...

```
const myFunction=function( theVar ) {
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'includes/file.php';


    if (theVar.includes('postId')) {
        url = url + '?postId=' + theVar.substr(theVar.length - 1);
    } else if (theVar.includes('userId')) {
        url = url + '?userId=' + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);
    } else if (theVar.includes('commentId')) {
        url = url + '?commentId=' + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);        
    }       


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          alert('Success!');
        }
      };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.send();
}
```

PHP test target

```
<?php

    echo json_encode( $_REQUEST );

?>
```

The response

```
{"postId":"4"}
```

You could modify the PHP to make it a little more secure by using prepared statements.

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === "XMLHttpRequest" ) {

        require 'connection.php';

        $postId = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $commentId = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'commentId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $userId = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'userId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $sql=false;


        if( $postId ){
            $sql='update `posts` set `postVotes` = `postVotes` + 1 where postId=?;';
            $id=$postId;
        }

        /* assumed similar table called comments */
        if( $commentId ){
            $sql='update `comments` set `commentVote` = `commentVote` + 1 where `commentId`=?;';
            $id=$commentId;
        }

        /* etc - users too?? */
        if( $userId ){
            $sql='.... etc etc ';
            $id=$userId;
        }


        if( $sql ){
            $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id );
            $res=$stmt->execute();
        }
    } else {
        exit( header( 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden', true, 403 ) );
    }
?>
```

Full, single page, demo

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && !empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === "XMLHttpRequest" ) {
        ob_clean();

        $postId = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'postId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $commentId = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'commentId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        $userId = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'userId', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        /*
            here you would con
        */

        $output=array(
            'post'      =>  $postId,
            'comment'   =>  $commentId,
            'user'      =>  $userId
        );
        echo json_encode( $output );

        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>ajax</title>
        <style>
            body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;padding:1rem;margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:cursive;font-size:1rem;}
            div{display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:center;align-content:space-between;align-items:center;flex:1;order:1;width:100%;}
            output{display:flex;flex:2;order:2;width:100%;justify-content:center;margin:1rem auto;}
            button{padding:1rem;margin:auto}

        </style>
        <script>
            const callback=function(r){
                if( r ){
                    document.querySelector( 'output' ).innerHTML=r;
                }
            };

            const myFunction=function(theVar){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = location.href;

                if (theVar.includes('postId')) {
                    url = url + '?postId=' + theVar.substr(theVar.length - 1);
                } else if (theVar.includes('userId')) {
                    url = url + '?userId=' + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);
                } else if (theVar.includes('commentId')) {
                    url = url + '?commentId=' + theVar.substr(theVar.length -1);        
                }
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                        callback( this.response )
                    }
                };
                xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.send();
            };

            const myOtherFunction=function( theVar ) {
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = location.href;

                var query=[];
                Object.keys( theVar ).map( function( key ){
                    query.push( key+'='+theVar[key] )
                } );
                url+='?'+query.join('&');
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
                        callback( this.response )
                    }
                };
                xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button type='button' onclick='myOtherFunction( { postId:808 } );'>Click me [POSTID]</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='myOtherFunction( { commentId:909 } );'>Click me [COMMENTID]</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='myOtherFunction( { userId:303 } );'>Click me [USERID]</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='myOtherFunction( { postId:808,commentId:909,userId:303 } );'>Click me [ALL]</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type='button' onclick='myFunction( "postId808" );'>Click me [STRING - POSTID]</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='myFunction( "commentId909" );'>Click me [STRING - COMMENTID]</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='myFunction( "userId303" );'>Click me [STRING - USERID]</button>
        </div>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the variable you are passing to your ajax function comes in such a manner i.e if its `postId` it comes as `postId23` then you when you use `if (theVar.includes("postId")` to check if it contains the keywords `postId` then you try get the id number by doing this function `theVar.substr(theVar.length - 1);` This is where you mess up because when you use the function `substr(theVar.length-1);` this will always return the last character in that string so if `theVar` is `postId23` the function substr() will return 3 as your id then you will get the url as `?postId=3` yet you expected it to return 23. easy way if the postId,commentId,userId are constants you will have to know where the string array position ends i.e if its postId the position it ends at is 5, then function substr() code will be as so `theVar.substr(5);` if the string is commentId then count the array string end position which will be at position 8 then code will be `theVar.substr(8);`

Also This is not a good way of handling the requests. You might have to change the way you send your variables to the function and how get the variables. In future it might cause errors. I hope this is helps you and anyone else out there.

Try play arround with this example about the `substr()` function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_substr

Comment: i think the function doesn't send the `url`

Comment: what about that variable $link where do you set it before assigning it to $postId?

Comment: connection.php holds the variable

Comment: try add this  `xhr.onload = function (){ console.log(xhr.responseURL)}` this will output your URL in the web console if it was successful in sending the url. then you can see what it really sent to your file.

Comment: place it after send();

Comment: i get the url as in alert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187417/discussion-between-carlos-murray-and-andrew06041990).

Answer (score 0):

Ok! There was a problem i

> required a file in connection php file

and the php script file

> wasn't finding

the file